# Printing elements from csv file using raw_input

Tags: python-2.7, csv, raw-input

How to print elements from csv file using raw_input?

Code:

```
import csv

inputYear = raw_input('Please enter the year: ')
inFile = open('babyQldAll.csv', 'rU')
cvsFile = csv.reader(inFile, delimiter=',')

dict = {}

for row in  cvsFile:
    year, name, count, gender = row  

    if (year == inputYear) and (gender == 'Boy'):
        dict[name] =  count

        print('Popular boy names in year %s are:' % inputYear)

# According to informaiton in 'dict',  print (name, count) sorted by 'name' in alphabetical order         

print("Print boy names... ")    
inFile.close()
```

Desired output:

Popular boy names in year 2010 are:
     Aidan  112
     Aiden  168
      Alex   93

Comment: Please tag this as python2.7(?), as Python 3 does not have `raw_input()`.

Comment: Can you give a sample of the contents of the file?

Comment: 2010, John, 124, Male /n 2010, Amy, 111, Female

Comment: The file contains both boy names and girl names, I just need the boy names and their counts

Comment: Sorry the out put is not .."male" and ..."female"; female and male are swapped to be "boy" and "girl" hence why the condition is to search for all "boy" names ...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
inputYear = raw_input('Please enter the year: ')

file1 = open('babyQldAll.csv','r')
fileContent = file1.readlines()
fileRows = fileContent[0].split("\\n")

dict = {}
for row in fileRows:
    year = row.split(',')[0].strip()
    name = row.split(',')[1].strip()
    count = row.split(',')[2].strip()
    gender = row.split(',')[3].strip()
    if (year == inputYear) and (gender == 'Boy'):
        dict[name] =  count
odDict = sorted(dict.items())
str = ''
for i in odDict:
    str = str + i[0] + ' ' + i[1] + ' '

print('Popular boy names in year '+ inputYear + ' are: ' + str)
file1.close()
```

Comment: It is giving output for me. Which python version are u using? 2.7 right?

Comment: Can you put `print fileRows` just above `dict= {}` and `print year, gender` just  above `if (year == inputYear) and (gender == 'Boy'):` and let me know what are you getting in the output?

Comment: output: 
`    ['2010, Ruby, 440, Girl\n]
    2010 Girl `

Comment: It seems your file is having only one row  and that too has a gender `Girl`. And the script will output only `Boy`s of the year given by the user. Hence, no output.

Comment: Is there no function you can add to the original code that would make it work?

Comment: It is working now as well. What is your expectation of the code? The present code is made to output all the boys of the year input by the user.

Comment: to get an output of:

'Popular boy names in year (eg) 2010 are: Aidan 234,  Bob 219, Steven 673'

etc

Comment: yes, its exactly doing that. Your csv file does not have any boy in that year. So, how can you expect the output?

Comment: even when I try a different year, say 2011, I get the same output

Comment: Can you please upload this file somewhere and give me the link?